# Handling redirection in ExpressJS while avoiding redirect loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my first time using Express' `app.all()`. When a user signs up through an outside oAuth provider, I still need them to provide an email after returning to the site. I'm basically setting them as inactive in the database and checking for `req.session.active`.

What I'm doing is

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.session.active) {
        if(req.path == '/complete_signup') {
            next();
        } else {
            return res.redirect('/complete_signup');            
        }
    }
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. How can I **correctly** check if the user is already redirected?

If you can suggest a method other than `app.all()`, that would work, too.

EDIT:

On second look, this is working, but none of the external resources (stylesheets, javascripts, etc.) seem to be loading since they don't match `req.path`.

Comment: That example is going to cause every unauthed request to go to /complete_signup. If you're using static or staticCache you can move that middleware higher then the route middleware so that get a change to serve those files before app.all() has a chance to eat it.

Comment: It's strange that your external resources aren't loading because usually the static middleware goes before the router.

Comment: DeaDEnd, the router middlware gets bound automatically on the first app.get/post/delete/put/all. So, if he binds a route before he sets up the other middleware, router will be the first in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `express-redirect-loop` middleware (which uses sessions since HTTP Referrer header is unreliable).  This will only work for requests that support cookie storage/jar (e.g. browser).

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const redirectLoop = require('express-redirect-loop');

const app = express();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'test',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

app.use(redirectLoop());

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendStatus(200));
app.get('/bar', (req, res) => res.redirect('/foo'));
app.get('/foo', (req, res) => res.redirect('/foo'));
app.get('/baz', (req, res) => res.redirect('/bar'));

app.listen(3000);
```